# How to replace dotnet40 with dotnet45?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm trying to install `dotnet40` via `winetricks`, but I've got the following error:

```
$ winetricks dotnet45
Executing w_do_call dotnet45
------------------------------------------------------
error: dotnet45 conflicts with dotnet40, which is already installed.
------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I remove `dotnet40` in order to install `dotnet45` package?

I'm using wine-2.0.4 on macOS.

Comment: Potentially a helpful link that may be related and point you to other links: https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/734 you may need to install manually but I only did very little reading.

Comment: Related: [How to uninstall a particular dll from winetricks?](https://askubuntu.com/q/360429/78223)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try running the wine built-in Uninstaller program. Issue from the command prompt:

```
$ wine uninstaller
```

See: https://wiki.winehq.org/Uninstaller

Answer (score 6):

For me, after uninstalling from wine, still had issues with installing dotnet452.
This command run in the linux terminal worked for me:

`winetricks --force dotnet452`

Answer (score -2):

Start with a clean wineprefix:

```
$ WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winecfg
```

Then install dot45 on the new wineprefix

```
$ env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet45
```